# sort an array last to first

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array Now i want to sort my array in ascending order. I try but it does't work. My array is

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 216
                [id] => 216
                [1] => 52.42
                [TRUNCATE(100*(sum(m.carbs/(m.carbs+m.fat+m.protein))/count(u.id)),2)] => 52.42
                [2] => 2014-07-22
                [Cdate] => 2014-07-22
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 217
                [id] => 217
                [1] => 73.91
                [TRUNCATE(100*(sum(m.carbs/(m.carbs+m.fat+m.protein))/count(u.id)),2)] => 73.91
                [2] => 2014-07-19
                [Cdate] => 2014-07-19 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 220
                [id] => 220
                [1] => 71.87
                [TRUNCATE(100*(sum(m.carbs/(m.carbs+m.fat+m.protein))/count(u.id)),2)] => 71.87
                [2] => 2014-07-18
                [Cdate] => 2014-07-18
            )
```

Now i want to sort my array as last to first index

2,1,0

I already write function but not work

```
function lastSort($a, $b) {
    $aLast = end(explode(' ', $a));
    $bLast = end(explode(' ', $b));

    return strcasecmp($aLast, $bLast);
}

$r=uasort($array, 'lastSort');diamen
```

Comment: Why don't you use an ORDER BY clause in your SQL Query?

Answer (score 1):

Because what you want is reversing an array, why don't use the PHP native function array_reverse ?

```
$array = array(/*... Your array*/);
$r = array_reverse($array);
```

This should saves you:
[array_reverse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php).

Comment: Remember the second parameter (true) to reserve the keys.

Comment: @hd. this is not mandatory as the keys in this problem are numeric and numeric keys are always preserved by the array_reverse ;)

Comment: My tests indicate otherwise http://codepad.org/1ZaiTMy1 http://codepad.org/I56sIV2q - I would expect `x => y` to be index 2, not 0.

Comment: @hd. Sorry I misread. You're right: ONLY NOT numeric keys are preserved

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_reverse` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

```
<?php

$array = array(0 => array("foo" => "bar"),
               1 => array("faz" => "baz"),
               2 => array("x" => "y")
              );

print_r( array_reverse($array, true) );
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [x] => y
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [faz] => baz
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [foo] => bar
        )

)
```